# JQuery slick carousel not loading, CDN loading error

Tags: jquery, slick.js

New to JS and Jquery and having an issue getting slick to load with a bootstrap jumbotron. There are 4 background images with the following div's inside of `.carousel` but they are only loading in sequential order and I am getting an error in chrome inspect that claims the slick CDN is wrong even through it is copied straight from the website. Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resource/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resource/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton|Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="./resource/favicon.png">
        <title>Jumpstart</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <!--Navigation Menu-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Start a Project</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        <img class="navbar-brand navbar-right collapse 
        navbar-collapse visible-lg visible-md" src="./resource/images/logo.png" alt="Brand">
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Website Header with Scrolling Images-->
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="jumbotron background jumbotron-bike">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>Get Going.</h1>
                <p>Jumpstart your startup with some crowdsourced seed money, or support one of our 300,000,000+ creators and get rewards.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron  background jumbotron-beer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>GET THINKING.</h1>
                <p>Meet like-minded individuals who will help fuel your creative juices.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron background jumbotron-flowers">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>GET CREATING.</h1>
                <p>Stop overthinking projects and begin putting them out into the world.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron background jumbotron-duffel">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>GET STARTED.</h1>
                <p>What are you waiting for? Today's the day for your next big idea.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="relative-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Jump In</a>
    </div>
    <!--Featured Project-->
    <div class="container featured-project">
       <div class="row">
            <h2 class="col-xs-12">Featured Project</h2>
        </div>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="./resource/images/featured-project.png" alt="Featured Project" class="thumbnail">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <h3>Defrost: A Documentary</h3>
                <p>by Leo De Firenze</p>
                <p>"DeFrost is a documentary about growing up in a little red house in a cold, harsh valley. 
                This is a story about my mother's childhood. This film attempts to capture vignettes of her upbringing â€” her family, 
                friends, pets, and eventual depature from a freezing valley in Northern Italy â€” through beautiful cinematography and narration."
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 ">
                <h3>Product Categories</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Art</li>
                    <li>Books</li>
                    <li>Crystals</li>
                    <li>Design</li>
                    <li>Doodles</li>
                    <li>Deedlybobs</li>
                    <li>Farming</li>
                    <li>Gadgets</li>
                    <li>Hoverboards</li>
                    <li>Jams, Jellies, Etc.</li>
                    <li>Magazines</li>
                    <li>Plants</li>
                    <li>Snakes &amp; Snake Equipment</li>
                    <li>Tables</li>
                    <li>Ventriliquist Figures</li>
                    <li>Yoyos</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Projects List-->
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
            <h2 class="col-xs-12">Projects</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 project">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="./resource/images/project1.png" alt="Proj1" class="thumbnail">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <h3>The Right Tights</h3>
                <p>by Riley Mae</p>
                <p>These tights are 50 denier, beautifully constructed, 
                    hand-dyed, and guaranteed to last (no more ladders!). Made with high quality, 
                    completely toxic-free materials. Custom colors available to all backers.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 project">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="./resource/images/project2.png" alt="Proj2" class="thumbnail">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <h3>Peppermint Smart Home</h3>
                <p>by Brian McDonald</p>
                <p>Instantly upgrade your home with technology that keeps your family and home safe. 
                    We've made Peppermint easy to use. Just talk to your phone and Peppermint will help you every step of the way.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 project">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="./resource/images/project3.png" alt="Proj3" class="thumbnail">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <h3>American Streetlife</h3>
                <p>by Patrick Wallace</p>
                <p>I've been traveling around the United States for the past two years. I've slept on hundreds of couches, 
                    more than a few benches, and captured my experiences in this 120 page photo album.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Having Trouble Section-->
    <div class="container-fluid help">
        <strong>Having Trouble thinking of an idea?</strong>
        <p>Inventorsâ€™ block strikes at the worst times. But thatâ€™s 
            all changed with Jumpstartâ€™s Good Idea Generator Lite (GIGLi).</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./resource/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>'
```

Here is the Jquery code:`$(document).ready(function () {

```
 $('.carousel').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        pauseOnFocus: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        // slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 4
    });

    var scrol = 0;


});`
```

It is also listed in a git repository to see it live here: https://github.com/solaini/Jumpstart

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Clear your cache & cookies and try loading the page again. If you still have the issue, try replacing:

- `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js` with .`/resource/slick.min.js`
- `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css` with `./resource/slick.css`

[Your code works good on my browser: see this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euL2r.jpg)